# Assign struct to struct inside slice of struct

Tags: go, range, slice, element

Weird behavior when assign struct to struct inside loop.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type A struct {
        a string
    }
    type B struct {
        A
        b string
    }
    var z []B
    
    c := A{a:"Test"}
    d := B{A:c,b:"Test"}
    
    fmt.Println(c)
    fmt.Println(d)
    
    z = append(z, B{b:"Test"})
    z = append(z, B{b:"Test"})
    
    fmt.Println(z)
    
    for _, x := range z {
        x.A = c
    }
    
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

Output:

```
{Test}
{{Test} Test}
[{{} Test} {{} Test}]
[{{} Test} {{} Test}]
```

Expected Value:

```
{Test}
{{Test} Test}
[{{} Test} {{} Test}]
[{{Test} Test} {{Test} Test}]
```

Check on this [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vrAgs7C6-R2)

Comment: As you range over your `z` slice, `x` is merely a copy of the slice element; that is what you're modifying, and that's why the modifications are not reflected in the slice itself.

Comment: so what should I use? pointer?

Comment: Pointers can be confusing, here. There is an easier way: `for i := range z { z[i].A = c }`

Comment: There was a typo in my comment (since corrected). Try again.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/H4nfZcm7ADB

Comment: alternative: https://play.golang.org/p/a40VFAuV636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, by iterating on `z`, you are making a copy of elements of `z`, identified as `x`. In other words, updating `x` doesn't mean you're updating `z` but a copy of it's elements. You should do it as follows:

```golang
for i, _ := range z {
    z[i].A = c
}
```

I've copied the same to [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_z2HinPH_TN).